# Compute the accuracy of a clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn

I have a set of points that I have clustered using a clustering algorithm (k-means in this case). I also know the ground-truth labels and I want to measure how accurate my clustering is. What I need is to find the actual accuracy. The problem, of course, is that the labels given by the clustering do not match the ordering of the original one.

Is there a way to measure this accuracy? The intuitive idea would be to compute the score of the confusion matrix of every combination of labels, and only keep the maximum. Is there a function that does this?

I have also evaluated my results using rand scores and adjusted rand score. How close are these two measures to actual accuracy?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have been through the sklearn documentation to read about clustering evaluation techniques, but what I need is really an accuracy measure. Many metrics are good for explaining the quality of clustering, and I've used them before, but they are not what I need now.

(I'm actually surprised that what I need does not exist in a package like sklearn or anywhere else, I'm sure I'm not the first one that has a problem like this.)

Comment: How many clusters/classes are you working with? If they are few, you could use a brute-force approach, trying all the possible combinations of corresponde between classes and clustering labels and take the best one

Comment: There should be around 10 clusters, but I will need to extend this approach at some point, so I would like a well-defined function

Comment: Well, if the number of clusters K is big then a brute-force approach may be untractable. Anyway, it would require you to try all possible correspondences between clusters and classes, but that escalates exponentially with K

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `sklearn` I suggest you use the package from sklearn for evaluation, and check out the find manual of sklearn.

The most important metrics are ARI and NMI (although AMI may be a good idea to use, too).

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-evaluation

Comment: I have been through it already, but what I need is really an accuracy measure. These two metrics are good for explaining the quality of clustering, and I've used them before, but they are not what I need now. 
I'm actually surprised that what I need does not exist in a package like sklearn, I'm sure I'm not the first one that has a problem like this one.

Comment: Clearing is not classification. The standard measures are ARI and NMI. Stuck to the established standards... The Rand Index (RI) is, in fact, an accuracy: on pairs.

Comment: The problem with the classification measure is when there is not a 1:1 correspondence. And outside of KMeans toy problems there never is a 1 to 1 match.